# Connect to Magento API with oAuth - get signature invalid error

Tags: java, magento, oauth, digital-signature

I am trying to connect to the Magento API using oAuth. I am stuck at the first 'leg'. I am following this page: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html#OAuthAuthentication-GettinganUnauthorizedRequestToken

And as far as I can tell I've done everything correctly. But I get the following message:

```
FAIL
Unauthorized
oauth_problem=signature_invalid
```

The issue seems to be with this line, where I'm generating the signature. However there could be other issues as well.

```
String signature = HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(KEY, SECRET);
```

Wondering if anyone can see an error here?

Or perhaps below:

```
public class MagentoConnection {

public final String KEY = "aplphanumericKeyFromMagentoDashboard";
public final String SECRET = "aplphanumericSecretFromMagentoDashboard";

// these are the value I want to receive in the response
public String oauth_token = "";
public String oauth_token_secret = "";

public MagentoConnection create() throws IOException {
    // will map the response to this object
    MagentoConnection mCon = new MagentoConnection();

    // this initial endpoint as specified in the docs
    URL url = new URL("http://magento-86076-239465.cloudwaysapps.com/oauth/initiate");

    // users org.apache.commons.codec.digest.HmacUtils
    String signature = HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(KEY, SECRET);

    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("oauth_callback", "https://<app>.io/redirect/magento");
    params.put("oauth_consumer_key", KEY);
    params.put("oauth_nonce", new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32).toString());
    params.put("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
    params.put("oauth_signature", signature);
    params.put("oauth_timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
    params.put("oauth_version",1.0);

    // Make the request
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }

    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    if (conn.getResponseCode() < 400) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());

        // Get the response
        String result = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());

        // Convert the response to Json
        JsonElement elem = new JsonParser().parse(result);
        mCon = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(elem, MagentoConnection.class);

        System.out.println("magento",mCon);

        System.out.println(mCon.oauth_token);
        System.out.println(mCon.oauth_token_secret);

    } else {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
        Reader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            System.out.print((char)c);
    }

    return mCon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Oauth-signpost java library for generating Oauth enabled consumer. Its a lot better, though your approach is good for debugging.